# Extjs 4 item with loader

Tags: window, extjs4.2, loader, items

I am using Extjs 4 and I have a `Ext.window.Window` which has a loader property:

```
this.HistoryWin = new Ext.window.Window({
                title: '',
                modal: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 400,
                closeAction: "hide",
                loader: {
                    url: "Requests/history.php",
                    scripts: true
                },
                buttons: [{
                        text: "",
                        iconCls: "undo",
                        handler: function () {
                            this.up('window').hide();
                        }
                    }]
            });
```

In this window, the target page does get loaded correctly. Now I want to load this page, as an item inside a window. I mean I want that my window to have multiple items and one of them be this loader. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one have solved and the answer is to add some panels with loaders inside window. For example:

```
this.HistoryWin = new Ext.window.Window({
                title: '',
                modal: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 400,
                closeAction: "hide",
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    itemId: 'OwnPanel',
                    autoScroll: true,
                    width: 688,
                    height: 300,
                    loader: {
                        url: "Requests/RequestDetails.php",
                        method: "post",
                        scripts: true
                    },
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    itemId: 'HistoryPanel',
                    autoScroll: true,
                    width: 688,
                    height: 300,
                    loader: {
                        url: "Requests/history.php?fromRestateWin=1",
                        scripts: true,
//                        autoLoad: true,
                    },
                }
            ],
                buttons: [{
                        text: "",
                        iconCls: "undo",
                        handler: function () {
                            this.up('window').hide();
                        }
                    }]
            });
```

and one important note. Make each loader to autoLoad or do not forget to load it manually.